# .show in jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails application. In the signup form, the user needs to enter a password before the sign up form can be revealed. We have more plans for this but in the mean time we are using jquery to do some simple show/hide the containers after a text field of the password equals to what we want.

Here is the code

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#the_submit_button").click(function(e){ 
      console.log('the_submit_button was clicked'); 
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("e.preventDefault"); 
          $("#protectivepanel").hide() 
          console.log("protectivepanel")
            $("#salespanel").show();    
          console.log("salespanel")
    });
  });
</script>
```

I took out this if statement for now because I wasn't sure what wasn't working.

```
if($("#representativepassword") == "signupnow"))
```

The code isn't stopping at all. I can see that in the console all the way up to console.log("salespanel")

Here is my div container (bootstrap) with id protectivepanel look like.

```
<div class="container" id="protectivepanel">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="representativepassword">Representative's Password</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="representativepassword" placeholder=" Enter Password">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="the_submit_button">Submit</button>
  </form>
<div>
```

Here is the panel that I would like to reveal after you click submit

```
<div class="container" id="salespanel">
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
         tons of hidden stuff, should I make sure the divs are completely nested correctly? I was quite careful when I was doing this but I figured a part of the form should still show. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

do I have a syntax error? is the `<div class="hide">` in the proper place? The protective panel is hiding after the submit button but the form isn't showing?

Comment: Its just a guess I may be completely wrong <div class="container" id="protectivepanel"> this div might be not closing properly! I guess where your form ends </form> after that you should close div as </div>

Comment: this helps but the form still isn't showing properly but thank you! it isolates this section to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC with Bootstrap you should remove the hide class instead of trying to use show

```
$("#salespanel > div").removeClass("hide")
```

We need to use > div because as specified in another answer the hide class is on first child and not on #salespanel

Comment: To go along this I would also suggest you do the same with the hiding : $("#protectivepanel").hide() should be $("#protectivepanel").addClass("hide")

Answer (score 0):

Try and replace your script with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#the_submit_button").click(function(e){ 
           $('#salespanel').show();
           return false;
        });
    });
```

You need a `return false;` at the end of your script

Answer (score 0):

.hide class in Bootstrap has the !important declaration.

```
.hide {
display: none !important;
}
```

Jquery's .show() add a "display: block", or "display: inline-block" to the element - but these rules are overriden by Bootstrap's "!important".

As pointed out in other answers, **use .removeClass('hide')** to remove this rule and create no conflicts.